# [XmlException: Root element is missing.]

Tags: .net, xml, iis

I am currently attempting to troubleshoot an IIS Web Application that works in conjunction with 2 other virtual applications. I am surely not a programmer by trade but an infrastructure specialist. I am receiving this error below after the drive that houses these XML files was filled up by a rogue client. After resolve the space issues we are still encountering this stack trace below. Any assistance would be GREATLY appreciated.

```
[XmlException: Root element is missing.]
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e) +76
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowWithoutLineInfo(String res) +61
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent() +3988220
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read() +151
System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean
preserveWhitespace) +112
System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader) +108
System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename) +87
NetVIEW.Settings.UpGradeOldSettingsFile() +109
NetDAQ.index.Render(HtmlTextWriter output) +3543
System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,         
ControlAdapter adapter) +27
System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter   
adapter) +99
System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean   
includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1266
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to include at least a simplified/trimmed copy of the XML that still throws this exception. Also, make sure the [java] tag is correct; it looks like .NET from here. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: Do you have access to the source code, and do you have any experience with using Visual Studio to debug code? If no to either, then I don't think we'll be able to help you much, I'm afraid...